# Restrict read access to amazon s3 bucket for only particular one client or limited listed clients

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, security, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

My client has an S3 bucket where they write some files and they have shared their accessKey & secretKey which I'm able to access from cyberduck s3 UI client but I need to automate this process of reading files so I wrote Java code using **aws-s3 sdk** jars to get access to that bucket but I am getting **Access Denied Exception**, had discussed with client to grant persmissions so that we can get read only access to bucket but they are saying we have restricted access to **cyberduck UI** client only. I did some r&d and found that access to s3 buckets can be restricted for particular http referrer but not very sure if it can be restricted for cyberduck type UI client only or any particular limited clients. Also operations allowed on s3 bucket can be enabled and I am using **listObjects()** and **getObject()** (which is enabled as per my client). I think my client isn't very sure about what they have done. So I tried to access it from **Dragon Disk s3 UI client** and I got same Access Denied Exception. I am trying to access through my **white listed IP address**.

exception stack trace is : -

com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 96924E9AF7DDBA9E), S3 Extended Request ID: aRS00z2jHkv8TWhyHlV9k0wYj/MYuMwcrwcDgqgK2frjtSEAgTZ+tv6//brhfofGQr/UBIOCMgA=
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1586)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1254)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1035)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:747)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:721)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:704)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:672)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:654)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:518)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4137)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4079)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.listObjects(AmazonS3Client.java:819)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.listObjects(AmazonS3Client.java:791)

It'll be very helpful if someone can comment or share something on this, If it is possible to restrict access to only one client or how to achieve this so that I can figure out what **bucket policies** my client might have set so that I can ask him to enable permissions that way.

Comment: Did you have a solution for this? I am getting stuck with similar issues

Comment: @user123475 I figured it out but its different . What I have mentioned above is not possible in S3 security bucket policies . You can restrict read, write access from some IP address or If you want to restrict or allow particular client then you can also mention HttpReferrer value .